# How do sites like etherscan and polygonscan get data from nodes?

Tags: go-ethereum, etherscan, openethereum

Sites such as [Etherscan](https://etherscan.io/) and [Polygonscan](https://polygonscan.com/) read and show the balance of native tokens of many addresses and the balance of internal contract tokens (ex ERC20).

Do these sites get all address data from node through [json-rpc API](https://ethereum.org/ko/developers/docs/apis/json-rpc/) every time?

Or, when you show it on the site, Does the site read and show the data of the node's state file directly?

If you are operating a node, I wonder if it is possible to read the balance of addresses by block height as if reading a file rather than json-rpc API.

The current goal is to find out the balance of all addresses whose balance is changed at a specific block height... The problem is that the speed is not enough to call json-rpc every time...

Answer (score 0):

Both Etherscan and Polygonscan get address data from nodes through JSON-RPC API.  The sites read and show the data either directly from the chain data stored by all of the full clients, or calculated the data from it.

See:

https://www.moonpay.com/blog/what-is-etherscan

https://docs.alchemy.com/reference/polygon-api-quickstart

By the way, Ethereum 2.0 progresses in epochs, not blocks, so I don't think you can use block heights.